# Find property without knowing where it is in the tree

Tags: javascript

Have a small question:

```
p: {
   s: {
     name: 'demo'
   }
},
   x: {
      'something': 'me'
   }
}
```

How do I get name without knowing exactly where it is in the object tree ?
Edit: How do I get to 'me' ?

Comment: Well... while my original solution involving `JSON.stringify()` satisfies your conditions.. i have added two more solutions which are recursive this time; one for the first appearance and one for the last appearance of the searched property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate recursively:

```
function findByKeyName(obj, keyName) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (key === keyName) {
            return obj[key];
        } else {
            if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] !== null) {
                return findByKeyName(obj[key], keyName);
            }
        }
    }
}

findByKeyName(obj, "name") //returns "demo"
```

Comment: This will fail if a property has a value of `null`, since `typeof` will return `object`, but then `obj[key]` will fail.

Comment: @tymeJV thnx works wonders, I was actually pretty close but hey you learn while you live :)

Comment: But what if the target key is not in the first object key and it goes into the first object and ends the search ? obj = {
    p: {
       s: {
         name: 'demo'
       }
    },
    x: {
       'something': 'me'
    }
}

how do I get to 'something' ?

Answer (score -1):

Ugly but true...

```js
var getValue = (o,p) => JSON.stringify(o).replace(new RegExp('.*?' + p + '":"([^"]*).+'),"$1"),
obj = {
    p: {
       s: {
         name: 'demo'
       }
    }
};
document.write(getValue(obj,"name"));
```

Well despite my ugly solution works perfectly i just would like to add my version of recursive approach for the public welfare.

The following will find the first appearance of the searched property.

```js
p = {
   s: {
     name: 'demo',
   },
   x: {
      'something': 'me'
   },
   y: null,
   z:  {
      'something': 'you'
   }
};

var getValue = (o,v) => {
  var ok = Object.keys(o),
       f = false,
       i = 0;
  while (!f && i < ok.length) {
   o[ok[i]] !== null && typeof o[ok[i]] === "object" && (f = getValue(o[ok[i]],v));
   i++;
  }
  return o[v] || f;
};
document.write(getValue(p,"something"));
```

And the following will find the last appearance of the searched property

```js
p = {
   s: {
     name: 'demo',
   },
   x: {
      'something': 'me'
   },
   y: null,
   z:  {
      'something': 'you'
   }
};

var getValue = (o,v) => {
  var ok = Object.keys(o),
       f = false,
       i = 0;
  while (!o[v] && i < ok.length) {
   o[ok[i]] !== null && typeof o[ok[i]] === "object" && (f = getValue(o[ok[i]],v));
   i++;
  }
  return o[v] || f;
};
document.write(getValue(p,"something"));
```

Comment: This is utterly horrible on a number of levels.

Comment: @torazaburo i have to agree.. but it's valid.